# OpenText Livelink Content Server call "GetNode" does not return any document

Tags: c#, web-services, opentext, livelink

Hi to all the community.

This question is related to a specific product called OpenText Content Server 10.5 (previously named LiveLink) and the usage of his Content Server Web Service (CWS).

We use a very simple call to retrieve a document using his DocumentID "GetNode" passing the internal Document Id:

This method works every time except when we retrieve some files like Microsoft Excel with xls or xlsx extensions.

Even a text file with "Hallo Word" in it, renamed to xls does not works!

My idea is that this could be:
a) a faulty web service and a patch is needed
b) we missed something in the LiveLink configuration to enable certain files.

Any help is moire than welcome

Thanks in avant for any support

---------- Part 2 -----------------

To be more specific consider that we have a document with ID= 229835 (also the Nickname has the same value)

1) With the **GetNode(229835)** we receive the following error: DocumentManagement.GetNode() failed on the Livelink Server. No results were returned. Check the Livelink Server thread logs.  (nothing on the server logs!)

2) With the **GetNodeByNickName("229835")** everything works fine.

3) With te **GetGUID(229835)** we first retrieve a GUID like "3F67..8942" and then with **GetNodeByGUID(""3F67..8942")** everything works fine.

So my questions is why the first command fail and the other two works?

Consider that this a "seems" to happen with certain types of XLS, XLSX, ZIP, DOC, DOCX files. The size is no more than 2 Mb.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the web services. That sounds like a defect in the installation. Which patch level do you run? Does it run on Windows (C# web services) or *IX (Java web services)?

Comment: I'm checking now the patch level. The system runs on windows

Answer (score 0):

The `GetNode` call returns only the meta data for the node.
You want to use `GetVersionContents`.

As a minimum you need to specify the `ID` and the `versionNum` for the required content.
The following code is an example written in Ruby, but it should be easy to translate the logic into a different language.

```
  #
  # get specific +version+ of a document +id+
  # if +file_name+ is nil it returns the content of the file as base64 encoded string
  #
  def get_version(id, version, file_name=nil)
    response = @docman.request('GetVersionContents',
                               'wsdl:ID' => id,
                               'wsdl:versionNum' => version)[:contents]
    if file_name
      File.open(file_name, 'wb') do |f|
        f.write(Base64.strict_decode64(response))
      end
    else
      return Base64.strict_decode64(response)
    end
  end
```